# Calculate Average Number of Days Between Multiple Dates with dax in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

Let's say I have the following data frame. I want to calculate the average number of days between all the activities for a particular account using Dax in power bi

Let say I have this:
[image]

I want a desired result like this 
[image]

How do I achieve this using DAX in power BI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the data in a table as in your picture, create a calculated column like this:

```
AvgerageDaysInbetween = 
var thisCustomer = [Customer]
var temp = 
SUMX(
    FILTER(
        SUMMARIZE(
            'Table';
            [Customer];
            "avg";  
                DIVIDE(
                    DATEDIFF(MIN('Table'[DateOfOrder]); MAX('Table'[DateOfOrder]); DAY);
                    DISTINCTCOUNT('Table'[DateOfOrder])-1;
                    0
            )
        );
        [Customer] = thisCustomer
    );
    [avg]
)
return
temp
```

Resulting table:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response but that did not really give me what I was looking for the average of 03/11/2019 minus 03/07/2019, 03/07/2019 minus 03/04/2019 and 03/04/2019. that is 4+3+3=10. 10/3=3.3. Any more insight?

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly