# 7 day Rolling Average - PowerBI - Power Query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to create a 7-day rolling average and automate this process with Power Query within PowerBI. I'm aware that I can achieve this via a DAX Expression, but need it to be in this way to facilitate the data export for the various stakeholders.  I'm expected to provide an additional two columns showing a 7-day rolling average based on 'Daily change in cumulative total' and a 7-day rolling average based on 'Daily change in cumulative total per thousand'

The data looks as follows:

```
Entity | ISO Code | Source URL | Date | Daily change in cumulative total | Cumulative total | Daily change in cumulative total | Daily change in cumulative total per thousand
Country Name | XXX | 06/02/2020 | 35 | 41 | 0 | 0.01
```

I've attempted to resolve this by referring to the following question but somehow couldn't manage.

[Calculate Average Number of Days Between Multiple Dates with dax in power bi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55410412/calculate-average-number-of-days-between-multiple-dates-with-dax-in-power-bi)

I also checked out a number of videos on YouTube, but somehow there were none that could address the issue through Power Query. I'm open to rethinking the way I do this.

Comment: What have you tried so far, please show us your code..

Comment: I attempted to implement the solution showcased in the following video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lcK8Ot0Vb6c

In the meantime had removed the code as I wanted to start afresh. Let me rebuild the whole process. Thanks for your help!