# How can calculate Average # of Days Between Multiple Purchase Dates in Power Bi, sliced by Date Range and Purchasing Customer?

Tags: powerbi, dax

So my starting point is demonstrated in this solution:
[Calculate Average Number of Days Between Multiple Dates with dax in power bi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55410412/calculate-average-number-of-days-between-multiple-dates-with-dax-in-power-bi)

That seems to cover everything I'm looking for but the ability to change the range of time being averaged via slicer. Wondering if it just needs some modification.

The goal is to calculate the average number of days between multiple purchase dates, sliceable by a selected customer and a selected date range.

the relevant table columns are invoice_no,customer_id and Date

I tried [Calculate Average Number of Days Between Multiple Dates with dax in power bi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55410412/calculate-average-number-of-days-between-multiple-dates-with-dax-in-power-bi)

I expected that changing the date range would change the average, even if it was in small amounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use a Measure when needing to use slicers and filters.

Here is my suggested approach:

1. **Create a Calculated Column on your table for days since last order**:

```
DaysSinceLastOrder = 
  var curCustomer = [Customer]
  var curDate = [DateOfOder]
  var prevDate = CALCULATE(LASTDATE('Table'[DateOfOder]), FILTER(ALL('Table'), 'Table'[Customer] = curCustomer && 'Table'[DateOfOder] < curDate) )
  RETURN DATEDIFF(prevDate, curDate, DAY)
```

Resulting in:
[image]

2. **Finally, create a measure for the avg**:

```
Avg Days Inbetween Orders = DIVIDE(SUM('Table'[DaysSinceLastOrder]), COUNT('Table'[DaysSinceLastOrder]) )
```

Example:
[image]

Comment: The calculated column using your suggested formula is blank, but also error-free. Any ideas?

Comment: I've updated the answer above to use `FILTER( ALL(...), ... )`.

Comment: That was it, thankyou!